# Custom Fields na Integração do Zoho?

Tags: automatização

Estou fazendo uma integração no Zapier, do Zoho Forms com o Zoho Projects.

Minha trigger é quando entrar um novo record no forms e minha action é para criar uma nova tarefa no Projects, porém ao customizar esta action, eu só consigo inserir o nome da mesma e quem será responsável. Preciso customizar principalmente a descrição da tarefa.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

OBS: Lembro que antigamente aparecia um link para (custom fields/new fields), porém este link desapareceu.